# Yaml, mapping multiple values

Tags: drupal, yaml, drupal-8

I am trying to improve upon the wordpress to drupal 8 migration module (https://github.com/amitgoyal/d8_migrate_wordpress) and add functionality to import taxonomy terms. 
I have written the queries to join taxonomy terms to posts, but am having trouble assigning multiple terms to a field (called tags, which is an entity reference to taxonomy terms) of my drupal content type article.
I have created a manifest file for mapping to my article content type:

```
id: posts
label: Wordpress Posts
migration_groups:
  - Wordpress
source:
  plugin: posts
destination:
  plugin: entity:node
process:
  nid: id
  vid: id
  type: type
  langcode:
    plugin: default_value
    default_value: "und"
  title: post_title
  uid: post_author
  status:
    plugin: default_value
    default_value: 1
  body/value: post_content
  body/format: normal
  field_image/target_id: post_image
  field_tags/target_id: terms
```

In my posts.php file, which handles all the fetching and processing of wordpress data, I have a function (prepareTerms), which sets the property 'terms', which is used by the yaml file above. If I set this to a single value then the everything works as expected:

```
$terms = '4';
$row->setSourceProperty('terms', $terms);
```

However, I want to set this property as an array (for multiple taxonomy terms), like below:

```
$results = $query->execute()->fetchAll();

$terms = array();
foreach($results as $term) {
  $terms[] = $term['term_id'];
}
//$terms = Yaml::dump($terms);
$row->setSourceProperty('terms', $terms);
```

As each taxonomy term should be a number (term ID), I should be just passing it an array of integers, but I cannot seem to map this to 'field_tags'. I have tried using Yaml::dump before setting the 'terms' property in posts.php.  I have also tried the changing the yaml template to hardcode these, like below:

```
field_tags/target_id: [1, 2]

field_tags/target_id: {0:1, 1:2}

field_tags: {target_id: 1, target_id:2}
```

Linked is a screenshot of a dummy node I created where I have assigned two taxonomy terms (loaded through devel) - https://i.stack.imgur.com/lRDX1.jpg

Any help stronger appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Fixed, it was simply a combination of incorrect array formatting, and setting the wrong target in YAML. 
My code now looks like:

Posts.php

```
#hardcoded
$terms = array(array('target_id'=>'1'), array('target_id'=>'2'));
```

Posts.yml

```
field_tags: terms
```